# Passing Redux value to child component in Angular 5 results in Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, angular5

**Edit 2**

I think I've narrowed it down thanks to comments by AntonioGarcía and smnbbrv. One of my components (I'll call it CompA) will always trigger a message, so I was calling an action to display that message in ngOnInit. I believe the notification component was being treated as a parent of CompA, so dispatching an action at this point is technically violating Angular's uni-directional flow of data.

So now the question becomes, what is best practice in this scenario? The text that is displayed is coupled to CompA so I don't want another component's action to know about it, and it is pulled from a config so I can't retrieve it in the reducer.

For now I am subscribing to the state changes in the top level component and checking for that specific state, then dispatching an action to update the text. Not ideal

**Original Post**

I am trying to build a generic notification component that takes a string message @Input and displays the result.

I am using Redux to store the message based on the state of the application, and it should update when Redux updates.

**Parent controller**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    template: '<app-child [message]="message$ | async">'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    @select() message$: Observable<string>;
    // Rest of code omitted
}
```

**Child controller**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: '<div>{{message}}</div>'
})
export class AppChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() message?: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**Error message**

```
Expression has changed after it was checked...
```

The two approaches I have seen for this scenario are to use an input property setter, and ngOnChange. Both lead to the same error, but for completeness sake here is how I implemented those patterns

**Input property setter**

```
private _message: string;
@Input() set message(value: string) {
  this._message = value;
}
get message(): string {
  return this._message;
}
```

**ngOnChanges**

```
public displayMessage: string;
@Input() message: string;
ngOnChanges(data: SimpleChanges) {
  if (data.message) {
    this.displayMessage = data.message.currentValue;
  }
}
```

I found a workaround to pass the entire Observable as the parameter and subscribe to it within the child component, but that doesn't feel correct.

Any thoughts? What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**

After smnbbrv's comment I decided to rebuild the app from scratch with nothing but the code in question, and it works as it should using property setters. Therefore I have not given enough information in the above post and will give more details here

The parent component's template also instantiates a router component which uses an ngSwitch to render the views of the application based on app state.

**Updated app-parent view**

```
<app-child [message]="message$ | async"></app-child>
<app-router></app-router>
```

**app-router view**

```
<div [ngSwitch]="workflowStep$ | async">
  <app-page-view *ngSwitchCase="workflowStep.PageView"></app-page-view>
  /* Other Views*/
</div>
```

**app-page-view**

```
ngOnInit(){
  ngRedux.dispatch({type: 'appPageView_Loaded', message: 'view loaded!'});
}
```

The idea being no matter which view you are on the notification component can still be visible and not tied directly to any one view. If any component needs something displayed it can

1. dispatch an action with a message which updates the store value which emits a change
2. app-parent's @select variable "message$" then updates the value being passed into app-child
3. app-child's @Input setter updates the message displayed

I copied all of the ts code from this parent controller into the new test parent component and couldn't reproduce the error, so that leaves the component router causing issues.

One view in particular (app-page-view) emits an action on init which updates the notification message property in the store. This causes the error where just a straight parent to child component does not.

Comment: please post the full code of `AppComponent`

Comment: I can't copy/paste since it is company code, but there are only three parts omitted. The first is the constructor which is bringing in unrelated services, the next is ngOnInit which uses those services to get some data, and a public method that calls an unrelated jquery plugin

Comment: There is quite a good post [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) about your error, maybe you can get something there.

Comment: @smnbbrv I updated the post with more information